# Nginx - Serve proxy pass target as IP instead of internal DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, web-hosting

I frequently use **Nginx** as reverse proxy for deserving all my internal hosted applications.
Most of the time, these applications are called with a IP-based address & everything works well.

This time, I want to proxy an wordpress hosted on a internal Apache2 server.
So I want to use internal DNS as a *VirtualHost* in Apache.

The issue is that Nginx always use IP instead of internal DNS to call Wordpress.
So I do not target on right VirtualHost on Apache.

How can I **force Nginx to use DNS instead** of rewriting it as IP ?

## **Nginx vhost configuration**

```
server{
  server_name http://my-external-dns.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my-internal-dns.lan/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_read_timeout    10;

    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
  }
}
```

### Specific proxy configuration on nginx

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffer_size   16k;
proxy_buffers       32   16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

### Nginx **access.log**

```
[01/Jun/2020:10:14:26 +0200] 109.190.219.189 (-) "my-external-dns.com" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2 => 192.168.10.10:80
```

> You can see it does use IP 192.168.10.10 which is IP of my-internal-dns.lan host.

It should be

```
[01/Jun/2020:10:14:26 +0200] 109.190.219.189 (-) "my-external-dns.com" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2 => my-internal-dns:80
```

## On Apache side, I've got this config.

> I think the issue is not there but on Nginx config

```
# My Specific Host
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my-internal-dns.lan
        DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/mydir/
        <Directory /var/www/prod/mydir>
                Options All
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# My Default Host
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        <Directory /var/www>
                AllowOverride All
                Options All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As said before, Nginx jumps to default host, instead of specific one.

Regards

Comment: Your problem is not the IP address, it is the value of the Host header in the request. You use `proxy_set_header Host $host;` which means Apache tries to match `ServerName` with `my-external-dns.com;`. If you remove that statement, Nginx will set the Host header to the value in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichardSmith => it works perfectly. I had a misunderstanding on this. (You should post your comment as an answer)